# Error creating a status transition programmatically - Missing bundle for entity type workflow_transition

Tags: 10, workflows

I'm currently working on a migration project from D7 to D10. I have a form that needs to go through several steps from creation to completion, here are some of them:

- New Request
- Under Analysis
- Manager Approval

The status transition is done through a button called "Save and Submit" which, when clicked, the form should go directly from the "Creation" status to the "Under Analysis" status.

For this, I'm using the "Workflow" contrib module - https://www.drupal.org/project/workflow - and created a status transition programmatically. But when requesting the transition I am getting an error.

Can anyone help me with this problem, please?

Here is my code and the error received:

```
public static function createNodeStatusTransition($node_id, $workflow_id, $transition_id, $field_name, $to_state_id, $user_id = NULL) {

$node = Node::load($node_id);

if (!$node instanceof EntityInterface) {
  throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Node with ID $node_id does not exist.");
}

$workflow = Workflow::load($workflow_id);

if (!$workflow) {
  throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Workflow with ID $workflow_id does not exist.");
}

$current_state = $node->get($field_name)->value;

$to_state = WorkflowState::load($to_state_id);
if (!$to_state) {
  throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Workflow state with ID $to_state_id does not exist.");
}

if ($to_state->getWorkflowId() !== $workflow_id) {
  throw new \InvalidArgumentException("The 'to' state does not belong to the workflow with ID $workflow_id.");
}

$transition = WorkflowTransition::create([
  'entity_type' => $node->getEntityTypeId(),
  'entity_id' => $node_id,
  'field_name' => $field_name,
  'from_sid' => $current_state,
  'to_sid' => $to_state_id,
  'uid' => $user_id ?: \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
  'timestamp' => \Drupal::time()->getRequestTime(),
]);

$transition->save();

\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t('The transition was successfully created for the node %node_title.', ['%node_title' => $node->label()]));
```

}

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting a bundle when you create your transition?

Comment: Yes @sonfd, although it is not necessary. Defining a bandle, I use the setValues() method, but I get the error that the wid cannot be null in the database. However, the setValues() method is not defined to receive such an argument.

Comment: Your error message indicates that the error is happening during creation, and it's complaining that you have not set a bundle. Anything you try to do after calling create() won't help resolve that error. Try passing the bundle as an argument when you call the create() method; set the bundle just below the entity_type.

Comment: @sonfd, I made the change you mentioned, and still, the error persists...

`$transition = WorkflowTransition::create([
      'entity_type' => $node->getEntityTypeId(),
      'bundle'      => 'workflow_transition',
      'entity_id'   => $node_id,
      'field_name'  => $field_name,
      'from_sid'    => $current_state,
      'to_sid'      => $to_state_id,
      'uid'         => $user_id ?: \Drupal::currentUser()->id(),
      'timestamp'   => \Drupal::time()->getRequestTime(),
    ]);`

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood the problem. I'm not familiar with the Workflow contrib module and its way of doing things. I've always used the Content Moderation & Workflows modules in core.

Comment: No problem @sonfd, I found the solution and I will post here how the solution turned out. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. Now it's working fine. Here's what the code looked like after the changes.

```
public static function createNodeStatusTransition($node_id, $workflow_id, $field_name, $to_state_id, $user_id = NULL) {

$node = Node::load($node_id);

if (!$node instanceof EntityInterface) {
  throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Node with ID $node_id does not exist.");
}

$workflow = Workflow::load($workflow_id);

if (!$workflow) {
  throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Workflow with ID $workflow_id does not exist.");
}

$current_state = $node->get($field_name)->value;

$to_state = WorkflowState::load($to_state_id);
if (!$to_state) {
  throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Workflow state with ID $to_state_id does not exist.");
}

if ($to_state->getWorkflowId() !== $workflow_id) {
  throw new \InvalidArgumentException("The 'to' state does not belong to the workflow with ID $workflow_id.");
}    

// Create Workflow Transition
$transition = WorkflowTransition::create([$current_state]);
$transition->setValues($to_state, \Drupal::currentUser()->id(), \Drupal::time()->getRequestTime(), '', TRUE);
$transition->setTargetEntity($node);

// Updates the field relating to the entity's workflow state
$entity = $transition->getTargetEntity();
$entity->{$field_name}->value = $transition->getToSid();
if ($transition->getWorkflow()->getSetting('always_update_entity')) {
  $entity->changed = $transition->getTimestamp();
}
$entity->save();

$transition->save();

\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t('The transition was successfully created for the node %node_title.', ['%node_title' => $node->label()]));
```

}